# Why is Ant Design's Modal component not updating upon parent's Table change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm struggling to have a [Modal Component](https://ant.design/components/modal/) closed when the mask (area outside the modal) is clicked.

I have a Parent Component, which is a [Table Component](https://ant.design/components/table/):

```
export default function App() {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Tribunal/Sistema',
      dataIndex: 'court',
      key: 'court',
      filters: [...Array.from(new Set(data.map(item => ({text: item.court, value: item.court}))))],
      onFilter: (value: any, record: any) => record?.court?.includes(value),
      render: (text: string) => <strong>{text}</strong>,
    },
    {
      title: 'Status',
      key: 'tags',
      dataIndex: 'tags',
      filters: [{text: 'coletado', value: 'coletado'}, {text: 'problema', value: 'problema'}],
      onFilter: (value: any, record: any) => record?.tags?.includes(value),
      render: (tags: string[]) => (
        <>
          {tags.map(tag => {
            let color = tag === 'problema' ? 'red' : 'green';
            return (
              <Tag color={color} key={tag}>
                {tag[0].toUpperCase() + tag.slice(1)}
              </Tag>
            );
          })}
        </>
      ),
    },
    {
      title: 'Histórico',
      key: 'history',
      render: () => (
        <Button
          type="text"
          icon={<HistoryOutlined />}
          onClick={() => setIsModalVisible(true)}
        >
          <AccessHistoryModal isVisible={isModalVisible} setVisible={setIsModalVisible}/>
        </Button>
      )
    },
    {
      title: 'Ação',
      key: 'action',
      render: () => (
        <Button
          type="text"
          href="#"
          icon={<EditOutlined />}
        >
        </Button>
      )
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Table 
      columns={columns} 
      dataSource={data} 
      pagination={{ defaultPageSize: 10, showSizeChanger: false }}
    />
  );
};
```

I need to update the following child Modal Component upon click:

```
export default function AccessHistory(props: HistoryData) {
    const closePopup = useCallback(() => {
        props.setVisible(false);
      }, [props]);

    return (
        <Modal 
            title="Histórico de acesso"
            visible={props.isVisible}
            onCancel={closePopup}
            footer={null}
        >
            <div className="modal-subtitle">
                Últimas ações realizadas no sistema do tribunal
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

I can see that the callback function `closePopup` is called when the user clicks outside the mask, but the function `props.setVisible` is not able to change the state of the component.

What do I need to change to have the modal closed when user clicks off the dialogue?

Comment: You want to keep the modal open if someone clicks off of the dialogue? Where is that in the code?

Comment: No, I need to close the modal if someone clicks off the dialogue

Comment: Either way. Where is it? `onCancel` isn't it. Read the docs on the modal behavior please. If you can't get it to work please repost.

Comment: If I assign the `onCancel` value to `{e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    closePopup();
}}` I got it to work, but I don't know why it works

Comment: It probably wont work in all circumstances, but the idea is correct. When clicking off the modal dialogue, it closes the dialogue. The event propagation is DOM dependent.

Comment: does it work without the `e.stopPropagation();` call?

Comment: No, it does not